# New user comment clarification

Tags: discussion, status-completed, comments, new-users

I know new users (<50 rep) can comment on their own questions/answers.  Can they also comment on others' answers to their questions?

If not, that should be allowed as well.

Answer (score 9):

Yes. This has been around for a long time, but you would never know it by how many people continually ask for the already implemented feature on UV.

Answer (score 9):

I updated the /faq on all sites to reflect this, because it was.. er.. a frequently asked question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they can. I've seen it done many times.