# Can low level users comment on answers to their own questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, reputation, comments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New user comment clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/new-user-comment-clarification)

One of the first things that many new users do is to ask a question.

People then respond, and there is a need for the original poster to provide feedback.

However, if the user doesn't have much reputation, they can't comment, so many resort to asking follow-up questions as answers.

Would stackoverflow be enhanced by allowing users to comment on answers associated with questions they asked, no matter what their reputation?

Comment: Ah, I couldn't find the duplicate (it was phrased somewhat differently) and it turns out that I was misinformed about that ability of new users to comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I believe you can comment on your own stuff no matter what rep. I even think i have seen this on many occasions.