# Is the ability of low-rep users to comment within their own questions adequately documented?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, reputation, comments

In [New user comment clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/new-user-comment-clarification), Joel asks if low-rep users can comment on answers to their questions, and the answer is yes. Rich B notes that a lot of people ask for the feature on uservoice.

Does this suggest that such an ability is insufficiently documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there continues to be questions about it, then probably it is not documented enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an issue of documentation, but that the types of users who have this particular question have no way of getting the "new user" experience short of deleting their cookies and asking a question.

Also, new users are often too clumsy to figure out how to do anything, so even if they knew they could comment on ANYTHING in their question, they'll *still* do it wrong.

So who are we "documenting" this for, then..?

EDIT: Since I wrote this, we've updated the faq to include that clarification.

Comment: "We do it for the kids!"