# Could some clarity regarding commenting be added to the main FAQ page?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, new-users, privileges

On the [main FAQ page for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) it gives a brief overview of what abilities you gain at different reputation points levels (with more detail given on the official [Meta-based FAQ for SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stackoverflow)). One detail that should probably be added to both of these is a clear description of what you can do regarding commenting at the starting level of **1** reputation point.

I've often seen situations where new users don't realize they can post comments on their own questions [as well as any answers they receive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/new-user-comment-clarification), probably because the FAQs say you need 50 reputation points to comment (so they don't even bother to try). This usually leads them to add their comments as answers, making a mess of things.

Perhaps the main FAQ page and official Meta-based FAQ for SO could have the following modifications made to their lists of reputation points thresholds for abilities:

- **+1** (default) Ask or answer questions, comment on *your own* questions (and their answers)
- **...**
- **+50** Add comments to *any* post
- **...**

---

**UPDATE:** It looks like some helpful modifications were made to the list of reputation points thresholds on the FAQ page, so I guess this is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). ;)

Comment: You can leave comments on any post at 1 rep on Meta.

Comment: @random: Yeah, this is more for people posting on SO (and thus for SO-specific FAQs), although maybe SF and SU FAQs could use the clarification too.