# Nudge low rep users to edit comment answers into their question text as well

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, comments

I so often edit comment answers by the OP into the question, that I wonder:

Can we have a notification when a low rep user comments on their own question?

Something like this for users below 50 rep:

> Make sure you edit relevant information from your comment into your question text as well, e.g. when you reply to a question asking for clarification.

Note that [commenting on one's own question is allowed for all users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/new-user-comment-clarification).

[Added]
One situation where this will not really work is:

- Someone comments suggesting updating the question with ....
- OP does that and comments *I have updated the question*

He/she would then get the reminder for something just done ;-)

Comment: How does the system tell if the user is trying to reply to a clarification request? Just popping with every comment (per user?) might not be ideal. But then again, some people clarify in comments without being asked to...

Answer (score 4):

I see the merit in ensuring new users learn to edit clarifications into their questions, but I'm a little worried a warning isn't necessarily the best approach, for three reasons:

1. As you pointed out, there's a variety of cases where the warning won't be applicable.
2. A higher-rep user may already be editing the clarifications into the post (which as you mentioned is frequent). Odds are the edit we asked the new user to make ends up discarded.
3. It might not be obvious to a new user what the warning is asking for (although this is something we might be able to address with copy).

---

I'm not sure what the best approach is here (I'd lean towards encouraging new users to pay more attention to the edit summary and inviting them to learn from it), but I don't think a warning is it.

I'm going to mark this as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) for the time being, but I'm happy to hear counterpoints and revisit.

Answer (score 3):

I agree this should be implemented and I had like to answer [some points Thomas mentioned as reason to decline this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/266885/245360):

> As you pointed out, there's a variety of cases where the warning won't be applicable.

So? It is a warning, not an error. Okay, users may be misinterpreting it, but doesn't that say more about the message being unclear? Why not take this chance to educate users?

> If a higher-rep user may be currently editing the clarifications into the post (which as you mentioned is frequent). Odds are the edit we asked the new user to make will end up discarded.

Again, not a reason to not show a warning. The warning gets shown *before* the user adds a comment, not afterwards, so there is nothing to edit yet. And even if a user was editing already, what is the point? Doesn't that happen all the time? How often am I halfway editing a post while I receive a notification someone else already edited? This is just a fact we should accept.

> It might not be obvious to a new user what the warning is asking for (although this is something we might be able to address with copy).

So make the notification clear. Link to a FAQ that explains it all. Show examples of good and bad there, and a user will understand.