# Feature of posting a question as an anonymous guest user (without having an account) is not useful and it leads to incorrect answers / comments

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, comments, unregistered-users

Posting a question as an anonymous guest user (without having an account) is allowed but for commenting 50 reputations are required.

A guest user (who doesn't have an account) can't accrue any reputation points.

Now, if a guest user (who doesn't have an account) posts a question and if some people respond with cryptic answers or wrong answers then the OP (the guest user who posted the question) will want to comment on these answers.

But, the guest user (who doesn't have an account) can't comment because he/she doesn't have any reputation points.

And if the guest user (who doesn't have an account) gives his/her comments as an answer then the answer gets deleted by the moderators because it is actually not an answer.

The downside of this is that the OP can ask only a question and that's it. The OP won't be able to get involved further in the posting.

Because of this, it is quite possible that the answers to the question posted by OP are incomplete / wrong / cryptic, etc.

And this is not going to help the future readers of the question.

Besides, if some user comments that the question is not clear, then the OP won't be able to give more details about the question (because he/she can't comment and his/her answers will get deleted by the moderators).

Involvement of OP is very necessary to make a question and its comments / answers meaningful for future readers.

But currently, OP can't get involved other than just asking the question.

So, please either allow guest user (who doesn't have an account) to comment also or please remove this feature of posting a question anonymously as a guest user (without having an account).

I have faced this problem myself and that's why I brought up this point. I had created this account mainly to highlight this problem. After the discussions are complete, I will delete all my stackexchange and stackoverflow accounts.

I am not saying that commenting as a guest user should be allowed. But if it is not allowed, then, the feature of posting a question anonymously as a guest user (without having an account) should also be removed.

Note: I am using incognito mode of Chrome. And I have setup Firefox to delete all history on exit.

Comment: A user can always comment on answers to their own question, no minimum reputation necessary.

Comment: The common case is user who lose the cookies used to keep the unregistered account, then indeed they can't comment anymore. But that's their problem, not SE problem.

Comment: Also, another wrong detail you bring here is "can't accrue any reputation points" - that's just wrong. Please check what you say before posting. Thanks. (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/425903/tom))

Comment: The guest user will ask a question and then the guest user will close the browser. Do you guys expect the guest user to keep the browser open for multiple days until all the discussions have happened on the post?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Is Sad And Angry : Can you please explain how a guest user (not having an account) accrue reputation points?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [New user comment clarification](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/new-user-comment-clarification) or [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Cookies are not usually cleared on browser close, meaning you can reopen the browser without losing the unregistered "account". Unless you have some unusual broswer and/or are running incognito mode, but then that's your problem.

Comment: I am not saying that commenting as a guest user should be allowed. But if it is not allowed, then, the feature of posting a question anonymously as a guest user (without having an account) should also be removed.

Comment: Are you using any browser extension that deletes or erase cookies? This could potentially cause the situation you describe. I'm not sure if logging in and out of the Q&A after creating an anonymous question would destroy the anonymous user cookie.

Comment: I am using incognito mode of Chrome. And I have setup Firefox to delete all history on exit. I don't think that a malformed feature is my problem. However, I can only report. I know that changing the feature is not under my control.

Comment: Using Chrome and Firefox like that will conflict with unregistered account usage as the browsers will delete all your cookies each time you close them and that disables your access to that account. The answer is not to do that I suppose. I.e. if you're going to use an unregistered account, don't do it in incognito mode.

Comment: Well, I use incognito mode of Chrome and I have setup Firefox to delete all history on exit  to stay safe on Internet. I will not change it just to ask a question on stackexchange as an unregistered user. Obviously, I have learned that asking a question on stackexchange as an unregistered user is not for me. And I don't want to create an account on stackoverflow / stackexchange. I had created this account mainly to highlight this problem. After the discussions are complete, I will delete all my stackexchange and stackoverflow accounts.

Comment: @Andrew If you use Chrome and Firefox in this way, then just don't use unregistered accounts.

Comment: You're basically saying: "The fact that I've specifically disabled how websites track me (i.e., cookies and local storage), which is how reasonable/responsible browsers track people who don't create accounts, causes a non-optimal experience when I don't register/validate an account. Thus, *everyone* who hasn't chosen to cripple all websites should be forced to not be permitted to have this useful feature." That's not reasonable. You've made a security-conscious choice to not permit persistent state to be stored by websites. Don't *impose on everyone else* the consequences of your choice.

Comment: Now, there are potential valid issues here, but "disable this for everyone, everywhere" isn't the right choice. First, permitting anonymous accounts to post questions and answer are, if I recall correctly, things that can be separately enabled/disabled for each SE site. Thus, such discussions should really be had on a per-site basis, unless there's an overriding issue which makes an all-SE choice appropriate.

Comment: A feature request for prominent notification to the anonymous user that they will loose ownership access to the question if they delete their cookies (e.g., if they have set their browser to delete cookies/state upon closing the browser or if they uses a different browser) would be a *much* more reasonable response to this situation. Helping users make an informed decision as to their choices by making sure they are aware of possible negatives is quite reasonable.

Comment: @Makyen : I checked few other sites of stackexchange/stackoverflow and those sites don't allow anonymous posting. Even this site (meta.stackexchange.com) doesn't allow anonymous posting. I think that majority of sites here don't allow anonymous posting. In my opinion, this means that this feature is not much useful. If this feature were useful then probably majority of sites here would have allowed anonymous posting but it is not so. So, it makes me believe that this feature is not useful and hence it should be disabled/removed for all sites of stackexchange and stackoverflow.

Comment: @Andrew Only a minority of SE sites allow mathjax. Does this consequently mean this feature is not useful and should thus be disabled on all sites, including math.se?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : Well, mathjax feature is not problematic in any scenario so there is no point in disabling it. But, anonymous posting is problematic in a scenario where the cookies are deleted on browser exit or the browser is running in incognito mode. Since anonymous posting has a problem and combining it with the data that majority sites here don't allow it, I have formed the opinion that anonymous posting is not really useful and hence it should be disabled/removed.

Comment: @Andrew Mathjax is for sure problematic: it produces inferior quality and thus hurst the eyes of users used to latex :) There are probably more latex users than users who disable cookies, so this would be a much more important change!

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz : Well, if that's the case then I am all for disabling/removing mathjax also. My opinion is that if a feature has some problem(s) and if only a minority of sites here are using that feature then the best thing would be to disable/remove that feature.

Comment: @Andrew Each community has their own needs. Just because something is not useful for the majority, this does not mean that it is not useful for the communities which use a feature. Stackexchange should not just do what serves the majority, it should support all its sites and their needs.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz :  Well, I actually don't want to argue more on this. I have only said things related to problematic features. If a feature is not problematic in any scenario then why remove it (even if only a minority of sites here are using it)? My emphasis is on combination of two things - Problematic feature + Very few sites here using that feature.

Comment: @Andrew the feature isn't problematic, the fact that you didn't know it behaves that way is problematic. A notice to users that deleting cookies will lose them access to the question solves that issue, while leaving the feature in place.

Comment: @Esther : This feature requires cookies but another side effect of this is that the user will now have to keep all the cookies from all the other websites he/she visited (Chrome doesn't have the feature of deleting all cookies except from one/few websites. There is no exception list in Chrome for cookies). So, to use this feature, the user may be taking a security risk by allowing all the other cookies also to be on his/her system.

Comment: @Andrew there are multiple ways to retain the cookie without keeping the rest of them. You can manually delete cookies from other sites, you can use one browser only for StackExchange sites, you can copy the cookie out of the browser before closing it and copy it back in after re-opening it, you can find a browser that allows you to make an exception for one site when deleting all cookies.

Comment: @Esther : I don't want to use another browser (other than Chrome) just for stackexchange/stackoverflow because other browsers may not be safe - so again, this is a security risk for the user. Regarding your manual solutions for cookies - """"You can manually delete cookies from other sites. You can copy the cookie out of the browser before closing it and copy it back in after re-opening it."""" Can you please tell me how to apply your manual solutions in Chrome?

Comment: wait a minute: I just noticed Chrome *does* have the ability to add exceptions for one site when deleting all data. Under settings->privacy and security->on-device site data (click Additional content settings) you can disallow all and add exceptions.

Comment: aside from that, you can go into dev tools, Application tab, click "Cookies" on the left, and you'll see the cookies on the right. They are key-value pairs. click a "Name" to see the "Value" at the bottom. You can copy it out into a file, and then you can click an empty "Name" field to enter a new cookie name, paste the value into the value field.

Comment: regardless of all this, it doesn't negate the fact that this is a feature that may not be right for you, but is definitely helpful to other people, so there is no reason to get rid of it. Internet safety is a personal judgement call, and most people feel cookies are fine. If you choose not to use them, that's fine, but you get to live with the consequences, not everyone else.

Answer (score 15):

The anonymous guest user (without an account) feature of Stack Exchange depends on cookies being preserved on the user's machine when they close their browser.

Those cookies are used to identify you as the anonymous guest user that posted the question and to give you the same permissions that registered, low-rep, users have on their questions.

If you choose to use your browser in a way that deletes all cookies when closing the browser, then the anonymous guest user feature indeed does not work correctly for you. But that is the result of how you use your browser and not a fault of how the feature was implemented.

Comment: I am of a different view. But obviously, I can't dictate stackexchange. However, keeping cookies is not safe. Please read this: https://blog.sucuri.net/2023/01/what-are-cookies-a-short-guide-to-managing-your-online-privacy.html - The data in cookies themselves aren’t harmful — and they can’t infect a system or website with malware. However, if the cookie data falls into the wrong hands, attackers may be able to access browsing sessions, steal personal information, or otherwise abuse your cookie data. (So, stackexchange is using an unsafe method. In my opinion, this feature should be removed).

Comment: Its a surprise to me that people on stackexchange don't think that cookies are unsafe. I thought that the majority of people who use Internet don't like cookies. Please read this: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-to-disable-third-party-cookies-for-1-of-chrome-users/498429/  - [[Google will block third-party cookies in Chrome for 1% of users starting in early 2024. This is the initial phase of removing third-party cookies entirely by mid-2024. Sites should audit cookie usage now and prepare for impact from the change]].
).

Comment: @Andrew, if you have a better mechanism than cookies to track which anonymous user posted which content, I am willing to listen. But I am afraid that any alternative either has the same security problems as cookies (if it involves storage on the user's device) or has severe privacy implications (if it involves storing identifying data on SE servers).

Comment: In my opinion, this feature should be removed. Anonymous posting should not be allowed. I have not seen any other website till now which allows anonymous posting. And I have been using Internet since 1997. On blogger.com (owned by google), you can post a comment anonymously but only if the owner of the blog had allowed it. But seriously, in 25 years of my browsing the Internet, I haven't seen a website till now which allows anonymous posting (except stackexchange).

Comment: Also, people are warned in the cookie disclosures that some features may not work if they don't allow cookies. The choice not to create an a account combined with the choice not to preserve cookies puts this squarely in the guest user's court.

Comment: @Andrew if you don't like anonymous posting, then don't do it. I'm not sure how the existence of the feature harms you?

Comment: @Esther : I had posted a question as an anonymous user. At that time, I was not aware that I will not be able to comment if I delete all the cookies from my browser. If I had known, then I wouldn't have asked the question. So, now, that question has got some wrong answers / comments and I can't do anything about them because I can't comment. So, this doesn't look correct to me. Also, those wrong answers / comments are not going to help future readers of that question.

Comment: @Andrew you can ask to merge the unregistered account with your account, if both use same email it should be simple.  More details [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous).

Comment: @Shadow Wizard Love Zelda : I faced some problems after posting a question as an anonymous user because I have setup my browser to delete cookies on exit. I had created this account mainly to highlight this problem. After the discussions are complete, I will delete all my stackexchange and stackoverflow accounts. I actually don't want to create an account on stackexchange / stackoverflow for asking questions. But since the feature of posting as an anonymous user was allowed on cs.stackexchange.com, so I used that feature but later I ran into problems because I don't keep cookies around.

Comment: @Andrew what I mean is that what you consider a problem isn't a big one as it can be solved by asking to merge the accounts.

Answer (score 4):

To enhance clarity, the "Post as a guest" feature can be enabled or disabled on a site-specific basis.

Examples of sites where this feature is disabled:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)
- [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)
- [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)
- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)
- [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/)
- [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

It is advisable to discuss this matter within each site's meta community and,
if deemed necessary, disable the feature with the approval of Stack Exchange.

As an illustrative case, the Japanese version of Stack Overflow has already disabled this feature
based on a [user request](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3751/).
At that time, no users objected to disabling this feature.

Comment: The list seems OK, but do you have a source for it?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227114/377214

Answer (score 4):

When you ask a question you have extra privileges on that question.

1. you can edit your question.
2. you can accept an answer to your question.
3. you can respond to comments on your question or its answers with your own comments.

In order for this to happen the site needs to know who you are so that you can have these extra privileges for your questions. We don't want to give them to everyone because then spammers might vandalise your question or add spam comments to it.

You can either

- register and get a log in and then log in with a password or via a Google or Facebook account.
- or you can use an unregistered account but then we still need to know you are you.

If you use an unregistered account and then delete all tracking information then you'll lose the above privileges because the site no longer knows who you are.

This is true of most sites, they all need to know you are you in order to give you special access to your data.